# MVVMLight DataTemplates in assembly ressource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

im using MVVMLight Toolkit for WPF and C#.
There is a WPF Application with a Window (Shell) and an Assembly where the Controls are (UI). The ViewModels are in the third DLL (BIZ).

The only thing which is displayed in the window is a control called "ShellView" which is the main UI Part. Im doing this to be able to reuse most of the application in different windows.

Currently im doing all the bindings between view and viewmodel in the "Shell" App.config.

I´ve referenced:

The assembly namespaces

```
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Application.UI;assembly=Application.UI"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Application.BIZ;assembly=Application.BIZ"
```

The Viewmodel Locator

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Application.BIZ;assembly=Application.BIZ" x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
```

And used the DataTemplates

```
<DataTemplate  
    DataType="{x:Type vm:ShellVM}">
<views:ShellView />
```

So if im bindig the Content of a Content Control to a class of "ViewModelBase" the View gets displayed automatically - everything works fine.

Now im trying to move the defintion of the data templates into the UI Assembly and just reference it in the window application. So all templating and binding is done in the UI assembly and the window just references all assemblies and displays the "ShellView".

My question is:
Is this possible and how do i have to reference the assemblies in App.xaml? Currently im getting lots of xaml parse exceptions.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, in your new project add a resource dictionary and add your template to it

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
 <DataTemplate  x:Key="Foo" >
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

And in your app.xaml

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            path to your Foo datatemplate for example
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyAssembly;component/MyFolder/MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and then from your code you just reference it as a StaticResource

example

```
 <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Foo}"/>
```

Comment: The data templates are not used in the main application window xaml. Only in the Control Library, would your solution work for this, too? I usually use them only for View-ViewModel binding liek this: <ContentControl Content="{Binding XY_ViewModel}" /> the data templates do the rest

Comment: @pwoestmann The app.xaml you can have in any project. However during the runtime only the one from the exe project is used. So if you wanted to stick with this solution you would have to duplicate this resources section. So one in the project where you want to consume your datatemplates, so the designer does not complain, and one inside the main project so when it runs it knows where to find them.